# Doctrine 2: Subselect in FROM Part

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is there a way to use a subquery in the `FROM` part of a query in *Doctrine*?

I want to build something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM community c, (
  SELECT *
  FROM ranking r
  WHERE r.id = 1
  LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
) as mr
LEFT JOIN user u ON mr.user_id = u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use a subquery in a FROM clause if you're using DQL. If you want to stick with it, you'll have to rewrite your query using only joins.

If you can afford more flexibility, you could try using the [Native SQL](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) api. Differently from DQL, it forces you to write your custom `ResultSetMapping` in order to correctly map your SQL result to objects, array or scalars, but it's very powerful and gives you the maximum flexibility possible.